# Reflection basics

Tags: c#, reflection

I am new to reflection and am hitting a brick wall trying to understand types.

What exactly does Assembly mean and what does `Assembly.GetTypes()` return?  Also if you call something like `GetGenericArguments()` on a 'type' you get from the `GetTypes()` command, what does that do exactly?

Thanks

Comment: You should start to read some docs about `reflection` http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) returns all the types and interfaces that are defined in the assembly.

Calling [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) returns all the generic parameters specified for a generic type.  This might not be the clearest explanation, an example would help:

```
var type1 = typeof(Func<>);
type1.GetGenericArguments(); // [ typeof(TResult) ]

var type2 = typeof(Func<string>);
type2.GetGenericArguments(); // [ typeof(String) ]

var type3 = typeof(Tuple<string, int, bool>);
type3.GetGenericArguments(); // [ typeof(String), typeof(Int32), typeof(Boolean) ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assembly is a dll or exe file in this case.
Assembly.GetTypes() returns all types in that assembly.

If you have a generic type

```
public class MyType<T, V>
{
}
```

Type.GetGenericArguments returns the `T` and the `V`.

Answer (score 1):

Assemblies contain code that runs, or stores information about objects i.e. classes/structures which have methods/properties/events.

A type is a class that describes other classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An assembly in .NET is a *.dll file which is produced by compiling a Class Library (and other) project types

`Assembly.GetTypes()` returns an array of all the Types in that assembly, which is to say all the Classes & Structs inside the assembly.

Further Reading

- [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)
- [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)